# Extending a real analytic function of two variables.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Suppose I have a convex open set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $f$ a real analytic function of $(x,y)$ in $\Omega$. Suppose also that $f$ does not blow up as I approach the boundary of $\Omega$. Can I always extend $f$ to be analytic on an open set containing the closure of $\Omega$? If not, what are the conditions on $\Omega$ or $f$ for which I can?

Comment: Well there is a necessary condition: $f$ must be continuous on the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: Ah good point. What if I assume $f$ and all of its derivatives are? Is this sufficient?

Comment: What do you mean by blowing up?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No ! for example :
consider
$f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x \in  \Omega= (-1,1)$

The other similar example in $R^2$ is $f(x,y) = -\sqrt{1-x^2 -y^2}$ for $x \in \Omega= B(0;1)$

I think you also need assume $f'$ does not blow up to $+\infty$ (and $-\infty$) as $x$ approaches to the boundary of $\Omega$ !